# Set $objValidation/Dropdown range from variable

Tags: excel, phpexcel

I am attempting to have phpexcel set the range for $objValidation based off a variable so not to have null values in my dropdown. This was my code

```
$objValidation->setFormula1('Index!$A$5:$A'.'count(Index!$A$5:$A$200');
```

which resulted in additional blank/null values in my dropbox making it bigger than need be. what I would like to do is something like this

```
$sql_temp = "SELECT `tempID`,`serialNUM` FROM `temp_sensor_specs` WHERE `statusTYPE`='SPARE'";
$result_temp = mysqli_query($link, $sql_temp);
$row_temp = mysqli_fetch_all($result_temp,MYSQLI_NUM);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($row_temp,null,'A5');
$count_temp = count($row_temp) + 4;

$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B4')->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list');
$objValidation->setFormula1('Index!$A$5:$A$count_temp');
```

So that didn't work I've also tried it in several variations as such

`$objValidation->setFormula1('Index!$A$5:$A'.'$count_temp');`

`$objValidation->setFormula1('Index!$A$5:$A'.count($row_temp) + 4);`

`$objValidation->setFormula1('Index!$A$5:$A'$count_temp);`

I really feel I've used syntax incorrectly, but can't figure out how. I've done similar range setting in loops `for( $i=4; $i<=15; $i++ ){
    $objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getDataValidation();` but also don't think this needs to be looped it should be a simple count and set that value as the count return +4 (as my dropdown starts on cell row 5)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So the proper syntax ended up being `$objValidation->setFormula1('Index!$A$5:$A'."$count_temp");